# Icon as the background in top right corner

Tags: html, css

I am working with an image that is part of an error message. I have managed to create everything but one small detail. The icon in the top right corner that is part of the backgrounds of the error message. I have never done anything like this before and I'm working with a responsive design.

I have created a fiddle with the code I have so far and I will later add JavaScript to make the message box close when the `X` is pressed:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLw6a8zr/

The picture I am working from:

[image]

Comment: What is "part of the background" ?

Comment: the icon, if you look at the original picture you can see a icon in the top right corenr, real big icon @O_Z

Comment: thats an image @martinj

Comment: @mrid ok, but you you help me out? lets just say this is the image I want in the top corner, I can change it later but not sure how to pake it by code:http://i1167.photobucket.com/albums/q627/deskdecode/alert-min_zpsz7khasfs.png

Comment: i'm putting up a code bro, wait :)

Comment: Just replace **n-wrapper** css properties to this
**.n-wrapper {
  width:60%;
  padding:20px;
  margin:0px auto;
  top : 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
}**

Comment: if im not wrong may be this is what you are asking i hope [Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLw6a8zr/1/)

Comment: @MJN that is exactly what im asking for. could you post it as a answer so I can accept it

Comment: yes, sure @martinj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `.net-content` classwith following code

```
.n-content {
    width:100%;
    min-height:120px;
    background-color:#d45659;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: url(http://i1167.photobucket.com/albums/q627/deskdecode/alert-min_zpsz7khasfs.png);
    background-position: 95% -50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 160px;
 }
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLw6a8zr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet I hope this will help you just changes in class **n-wrapper**.

```
.n-wrapper {
  width:60%;
  padding:20px;
  margin:0px auto;
  top : 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
}
```

```css
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
body {
  background-color:#423a4a;
}

.n-wrapper {
 width:60%;
 padding:20px;
  margin:0px auto;
  top : 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
}

.n-content {
 width:100%;
 min-height:120px;
 background-color:#d45659;
 box-shadow:0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.n-h1 {
 color:#fff;
 font-size:22px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #c04c4f;
 padding:5px 25px;
}

.n-p {
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18px;
 border-top:1px solid #ff686c;
 padding:30px;
}

.n-button {
 width:100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 text-align:right;
 padding:20px;
}

.n-button-white {
 color:#fff;
 outline:none;
 background-color:#bfbfbf;
 border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
 border-radius:4px;
 width:20%;
 min-width:120px;
 margin-right:20px;
 padding:10px;
}
.n-button-red {
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#d45659;
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid #c04c4f;
 border-radius:4px;
 width:20%;
 min-width:120px;
 margin-right:40px;
 padding:10px;
}

.n-close {
 font-weight:500;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:right;
 padding:15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.n-close:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#f8f4ff;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="n-wrapper">
 <div class="n-content">
  <div class="n-close">X</div>

  <h1 class="n-h1">Headline</h1>
  
  <p class="n-p">
   some text
  </p>

  <div class="n-button">
   <button class="n-button-white">Dicline</button>
   <button class="n-button-red">Accept</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea :

```css
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
body {
  background-color:#423a4a;
}

.cross-img{
  position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 2;
   right: 10px;
   top: -30px;
   opacity: 0.3;
}

.cross-img img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color : transparent;
}

.n-wrapper {
 width:60%;
 padding:20px;
}

.n-content {
  position: relative;
 width:100%;
 min-height:120px;
 background-color:#d45659;
 box-shadow:0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.n-h1 {
 color:#fff;
 font-size:22px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #c04c4f;
 padding:5px 25px;
}

.n-p {
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18px;
 border-top:1px solid #ff686c;
 padding:30px;
}

.n-button {
 width:100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 text-align:right;
 padding:20px;
}

.n-button-white {
 color:#fff;
 outline:none;
 background-color:#bfbfbf;
 border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
 border-radius:4px;
 width:20%;
 min-width:120px;
 margin-right:20px;
 padding:10px;
}
.n-button-red {
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#d45659;
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid #c04c4f;
 border-radius:4px;
 width:20%;
 min-width:120px;
 margin-right:40px;
 padding:10px;
}

.n-close {
  z-index: 50
 font-weight:500;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:right;
 padding:15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.n-close:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#f8f4ff;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="n-wrapper">
 <div class="n-content">
  <div class="cross-img">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUYyXH9xufRPuLvuln6MiroZuUJ9rlTaqaJ2mOo0kgEths4JxL">
</div>
  <div class="n-close">X</div>

  <h1 class="n-h1">Headline</h1>
  
  <p class="n-p">
   some text
  </p>

  <div class="n-button">
   <button class="n-button-white">Dicline</button>
   <button class="n-button-red">Accept</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cal also use like this. **.net-content** class with following code.

```
.n-content {
    width:100%;
    min-height:120px;
    background: #d45659 url(top-right.png) no-repeat top right;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```